# Can't send Javascript variable though AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

So in this script the variable "`encrypted`" is supposed to be sent through the ajax and passed on to `upload.php`, but I can't get it to do that. Lets say in the ajax I replace "`encrypted`" variable with a different variable, it works. Why cant I send variable "`encrypted`" through ajax to `upload.php`?

```
<script src="http://cryptojs.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
    var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // variables to be sent to php
        var formData = {
            'encrypted_data': encrypted
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                url: 'upload.php', // the url where we want to POST
                data: formData, // our data object
                dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                encode: true
            })
            // using the done promise callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // log data to the console so we can see
                console.log(data);

                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
            });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Move your script reference for aes.js so it's above the script block with your own code.

Comment: Tried it, Didn't work

Comment: Get any errors in the console?

Comment: In a demo `JSON.stringify` fails because the `encrypted` object has circular property references: http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/PPwwVV?editors=001. JQuery exceeds the call stack size without stringify because JQuery's extend logic is traveling the circular reference paths over and over.

Answer (score 1):

your var `encrypted` is an object, you should serialize it:

```
var formData = {
    encrypted_data: JSON.stringify(encrypted)
};
```

or send any of the properties you need:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");

alert(encrypted.key);        // 74eb593087a982e2a6f5dded54ecd96d1fd0f3d44a58728cdcd40c55227522223
alert(encrypted.iv);         // 7781157e2629b094f0e3dd48c4d786115
alert(encrypted.salt);       // 7a25f9132ec6a8b34
alert(encrypted.ciphertext); // 73e54154a15d1beeb509d9e12f1e462a0
```

Comment: Something else is wrong in your code then Pigman because this answer works. [Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/epmmoB?editors=001) where I pick the properties he used in his answer off of your `encrypted` object. `formData` is a serialized string of an object with just those properties, eliminating the circular references.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used CryptoJS so I'm just guessing here but did you declare CryptoJS? It's not in your code. Documentation - http://cryptojs.altervista.org/api/#AES

```
var CryptoJS = new Crypt();
```